# May we interact with a psql script?

Tags: postgresql

Can we do something like

```
\echo 'Type username to show its properties';
SELECT * FROM mY_users WHERE username = ?;
\echo 'End of script';
```

in a psql script file ?

The system would wait until we enter something then echo the 'End of script' string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just realized that internal doesn't mean variable defined into postgresql.conf.

So, I can use  `\prompt`

```
\prompt 'Please, enter an username ', my_user
SELECT * FROM mY_users WHERE username = :my_user;
\echo 'End of script'
```

---

EDIT

Like command \echo, you don't need to add a `;`  at the end. In fact, if you add one when using `\prompt`, you get an error.

You can show use the value read from the stdin.

```
\echo 'Here\'s the value read from stdin : ' :my_user
```

Answer (score 2):

The COPY command can, perhaps, help interaction with stdin,

```
 COPY t(a) FROM stdin;
```

This example do the same as

```
\prompt 'Please, enter a string ', mystr
insert into t(a) values ( ':mystr' );
```

with less confusion with quotes, and the possibility of do a massive inputing task.

Answer (score -1):

Would substitution variables accomplish what you need?

http://www.oracle.com/technology/support/tech/sql_plus/htdocs/sub_var.html