# Is there accept/prompt for postgres?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, prompt

is there any ways to create user-defined prompt in postgres as we can use accept/prompt in oracle?

in oracle we can use command like this :

```
ACCEPT hired DATE FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyy' DEFAULT '01/01/2003'-
PROMPT 'Enter date hired:
```

i want to use this in postgres.

Thanks before :)

Comment: ACCEPT and PROMPT are **not** "Oracle commands", they are SQL*Plus commands. If you use a tool other than SQL*Plus those won't work either

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746231/may-we-interact-with-a-psql-script  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL is just a database that simply executes statements, performs queries and returns results.

The makers of PostgreSQL did very well in not implementing functions as those you are asking for, because this would lead to transactions that survive over the user input phase, and this is generally a bad thing.

Comment: Yeah, Oracle was written back when operating systems were crude and simple, and Oracle had to provide a whole package for development and optimized performance.  pgsql OTOH takes advantage of living on more modern OSes where we have lots of optimizations and scripting languages.  I'd suggest learning something like perl, php, tcl, bash etc to do this kind of stuff in.

Comment: thanks guys for your explanation. i very much apreciated. because i want to make a function for querying the data. in my office there's policy that the DBA not allowed to querying directly into database. i want to make a procedure/ function to manipulate the data on my database

Comment: Shouldn't the DBA rather be the first one to be allowed to query the database? Who if not he is able to know of the consequences?