# Creation of a procedure [POSTGRES]

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, procedure

How to create a procedure that asks for a user name and return the following select:

```
select application_name, client_hostname
from pg_stat_activity
where usename=p_nameuser;
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: you will have `select * from your_function(USERNAME)` instead - is it worth of?..

Comment: A procedure (actually a function in Postgres) can not "ask" for anything. It runs on the server and cannot interact with the user - only the user's application can "ask" the user something.

Comment: I mean procedure like this "create or replace function functionusername (p_nameuser IN usename.pg_stat_activity%type)"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is possible only in psql - command "\prompt". See here - http://manojadinesh.blogspot.de/2013/11/interactive-postgresql-script.html or here - [May we interact with a psql script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746231/may-we-interact-with-a-psql-script)

Comment: I mean procedure like this "create or replace function functionusername (p_nameuser IN usename.pg_stat_activity%type)"

Comment: Classical pl/pgsql cannot do this. But you can create procedure to do what you want + combine it with \prompt in psql - see in first link, I guess it is what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a function that has a parameter and returns that information, use:

```
create or replace function show_activity(p_username varchar)
as
$$
  select application_name, client_hostname
  from pg_stat_activity
  where usename = p_username;
$$
language sql;
```

See the manual for many more examples on how to create functions:

- [create function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-EXAMPLES)
- [creating SQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html)
- [creating PL/pgSQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)